# Suppress a event from eventviewer

Tags: sql-server-2014

Is there any way to suppress an event logging in event viewer.
I am getting below event id 10028 which is getting logged in eventvwr.I know the reason why it is getting logged. Can I know if any way of suppressing this event id in eventvwr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce the number of things SQL Server puts in the windows event viewer?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46785/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-things-sql-server-puts-in-the-windows-event-viewer)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with database administration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to suppress specific events (with the exception of log backups using `TF3226` or using the `-n` startup parameter which suppresses **all** events as ably described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46785/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-things-sql-server-puts-in-the-windows-event-viewer)).

What you should probably be doing is addressing the root cause of the issue.  If you have decided not to do that, you can simply suppress the ids when you *report* on your event log.  There are a few ways to do this:

1. Use Filters in Windows Event Viewer
   Click the 'Filter' button on the right-hand side, and enter the ids you want to suppress preceded with a minus sign, eg

[image: Event Viewer Filter]

2. Using Powershell cmdlet `Get-EventLog` and filtering the output, eg

   ```
   Get-EventLog Application -Newest 100 | Where-Object { $_.EventID -ne 3014} | Format-Table TimeWritten, EventID, Message -auto
   ```

In summary, try filtering the event ids at your reporting time, rather than trying to suppress them altogether.  At least if they are recorded in the event log, they could be analysed by someone else or for another purpose.

HTH